I got a cors error but corsproxy.io is not working now. so is ther any athor tools for it?
I got a cors error but corsproxy.io is not working now. so is ther any athor tools for it? plees tellme. and also backend is not in my hand, becose Iam fetching the data from swiggy live api
I have tryed corsproxy.io thsi is a tool for avoid this error but I did not get expected result.and also I can't creat proxy bicos I have't backend, so is this corect. I expect the tool samiler to corsproxy.io wher we can over come the cors ishu.
